# apply conditional formattiong to all sheets in a folder in google sheets in a drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a lot of sheets I put them in a folder.
I wanna apply formatting to all the sheets. like making borders, making first row bold and applying conditional formatting. other thing goes perfect but there goes some problem with conditional formatting. it says TypeError: Sheet is not an XML object. on every start of conditional formatting. the code is:

```
      function ledgerformatting() {
    var fol = "1mg729p0ARzfxbdWTJQ23zELfeXQElP-v";
    var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(fol).getFiles();
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next().getId();
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(folder).getActiveSheet()
    spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('date');
    spreadsheet.getRange('C1').activate();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('debited');
    spreadsheet.getRange('D1').activate();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('credited');
    spreadsheet.getRange('A1:E1').activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setFontWeight('bold')
    .setHorizontalAlignment('right')
    .setBorder(null, null, true, null, null, null, '#000000',             SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
    spreadsheet.getRange('E:E').activate();
    var conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet..getConditionalFormatRules();
    conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('E1:E1000')])
    .whenCellNotEmpty()
    .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
    .build());
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules   (conditionalFormatRules);
    conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet  ().getConditionalFormatRules();
    conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1,    SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('E1:E1000')])
    .whenFormulaSatisfied('=if')
   .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
   .build());
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules    (conditionalFormatRules);
     conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet ().getConditionalFormatRules();
    conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1,  SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('E1:E1000')])
    .whenFormulaSatisfied('=i')
    .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
    .build());
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules (conditionalFormatRules);
    conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet ().getConditionalFormatRules();
    conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1,  SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('E1:E1000')])
    .whenFormulaSatisfied('=$B1')
    .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
    .build());
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules (conditionalFormatRules);
    conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet ().getConditionalFormatRules();
    conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1,  SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('E1:E1000')])
    .whenFormulaSatisfied('=$B1:B')
    .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
    .build());
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules (conditionalFormatRules);
    conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet ().getConditionalFormatRules();
    conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('E1:E1000')])
    .whenFormulaSatisfied('=$B1:B2')
    .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
    .build());
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
    conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
    conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('E1:E1000')])
    .whenFormulaSatisfied('=$B1:B2=""')
    .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
    .build());
      spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
      conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
      conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
     .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('E1:E1000')])
     .whenFormulaSatisfied('=$B1:B2=""')
      .build());
     spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
      conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
      conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
     .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('E1:E1000')])
     .whenFormulaSatisfied('=$B1:B2=""')
     .setFontColor('#FFFFFF')
     .build());
      spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules (conditionalFormatRules);
    };
      }
```

Comment: yeah on this line I get error where I put tow dots.
actually I have wrote this code for single spreadsheet via macro recording but now I am applying it to all sheets in a folder so I got problem

Comment: not yet after removing dot.

Comment: spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
for this line I get    problem TypeError: Cannot find function getActiveSheet in object Sheet. (line 162, file "Code")

Comment: this is link of folder for which I wanna apply the conditional formatting
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mg729p0ARzfxbdWTJQ23zELfeXQElP-v
and the code I wanna run on  https://script.google.com

Comment: ok this is code link https://script.google.com/d/17XgY2_FjT0NI6yr_brSj-s9sMWAwCTnTva_RxsM8rrRN0TWvbmhgI9P8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: oh sorry, I got it now

Answer (score 1):

I've corrected only a part of your code so here are the problems:

1. remove the `..` two dots on line 18.
2. secondly rename in a proper way your variables to prevent you from using `spreadsheet` when you are using `sheet`
3. read documentation carefully
4. place your retrieved objects into variables (sheet, range, spreadsheet...) in to prevent you from calling multiple times function like `getActiveSomething()`.
5. repeat the procedure to every conditional formatting elements in order to make your code fully work

so here's the corrected code:

```
  function ledgerformattingCorrected() {
  var fol = "1mg729p0ARzfxbdWTJQ23zELfeXQElP-v";
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(fol).getFiles();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next().getId();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(folder).getActiveSheet()
    sheet.getRange('A1').setValue('date');
    sheet.getRange('C1').setValue('debited');
    sheet.getRange('D1').setValue('credited');
    sheet.getRange('A1:E1').setFontWeight('bold')
      .setHorizontalAlignment('right')
        .setBorder(null, null, true, null, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
    var range = sheet.getRange('E:E');
  var conditionalFormatRules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([range])
  .whenCellNotEmpty()
  .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
  .build());
  //continue pushing other format rules as so:
  //conditionalFormatRules.push(newConditionalFormatRule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  }
}
```

**REFERENCES**

[Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)

Comment: I see what you mean , you mean put all the conditionnal Format Rules inside `conditionalFormatRules`right?? Well it should continue because there are other formatting rules that he needs to deal with